# Does a dishwasher require a disposal?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

I'm thinking of installing a dishwasher.  Unfortunately, my kitchen layout would not allow me to install it beside the sink (without moving the whole sink & cabinet).  So, I'd like to install it along another wall.

My question - can I just run a new water supply and drainage to this spot (and electric)?  I have good access under the floor, via my basement.  Or, does the drain really need to go to a disposal?  I've seen dishwashers that have a "hard food disposer" feature, but I'm not sure if this replaces the sink's disposal, or just helps clear large items out of the tub interior during washes.

Answer (score 6):

Dishwashers are no longer being connected to garbage disposals, though that was the previous way and it grandfathered in for anyone that already has it installed this way. If you are plumbing a new trap in another part of your kitchen for the dishwasher, remember that it will require a vent.

See also [Shirlock's answer here.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/3501/2196)

Comment: In many jurisdictions, (new) garbage disposals are no longer allowed, though likely existing ones are grandfathered in.