# Is a disposer required for dishwasher permanent installation?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher, garbage-disposal

Just wondering, since I haven't seen a house in decades that had a dishwasher but didn't have a sink-drain grinder.

I have heard that connecting it this way is partly done so there's an air gap between dishwasher and drains, and I'm guessing that installing without the macerator might require a vacuum breaker or something of that sort... but I'd sorta liks to know for sure.

(My place has both, but I'd really be just as glad to jettison the macerator.)

Comment: A disposal is NOT a replacement for an air gap.  An air gap is still needed even when a disposal is used.

Comment: Here's another question that's basically the same: http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/15021/43874

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had several houses with a dishwasher but not a garbage disposal. I don't think it really changes the installation that much... the dishwasher waste pipe connects to the sink drain before the trap.

[image]

If you want to plumb the dishwasher somewhere there isn't a sink already, you need to install a trap & standpipe, similar to the way a washing machine is done.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity-check . If/when the disposal dies, I'm inclined to just put in pipe.